Strange bearings of Shimano FH-MT410-B
I have Orbea Occam H10 2022, coming with FH-MT410-B rear hub. Recently it stopped working (it moves along with the rear wheel, no free move), before that I was hearing grinding sounds.
I've removed the cassette, removed the free-hub body and found these bearings smashed along with their s-shaped ball collar (I think the correct name is radial bearing). The balls were in pieces and one of them fell inside a pawl and it blocked the free move. 
I cleaned the metal ball parts, put freehub-body back, installed the cassette, but then the cassette start wobbling a lot and making strange metal rubbing sounds:



My question: what are these radial bearing do between freeHub body and axle bearings ? and how to find a replacement?
It seems like they are like seal or taking space to not have that wobbling. I've watch many videos in Youtube for dissembling/removing this freeHub body and didn't see anyone removing such part. Also the documents Exploded view is not showing this part exists somewhere:
https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/shimano/FH-MT410-B.html (exploded view)

As far as I can tell from the exploded view, that hub does not contain any loose ball bearings (i.e. all the bearings in it are cartridge bearings). So if you have a part like the one in the picture falling out, it means one of the bearing cartridges has broken and needs replacement. If the part fell of the freewheel body (part number Y3HU98020), then you need a new one. Luckily they seem to be readily available. If the part fell from either of the two hub bearings (part number Y3HV48000), then those likely can be replaced in a local bike shop with any standard sized brearing (no need to go for a Shimano branded part).
The s-shaped ball collar is called the "bearing crown".

But it seems all cartridge bearings are on their places and I understand these bearings are inside the cartridge. So they somehow slipped away from the cartridge ? so how to identify from which one? and how does will solve the wobbling problem ?

It would be helpful if you could take photos of the bearings in the freehub body. Then we don't have to guess if we're just having a miscommunication here.

It’s the freehub part Y3HU98020 giving a live action exploded view. Freehubs are generally not user serviceable and can be considered consumable. Order a new one.

my worries about buying a new one is that the problem may persists. So I want to know from where exactly is the problem, I can remove the free-hub body from the hub and post photos, but don't want to disassembly the body hub

The hub/axle bearings are marked part 3 - Y3HV48000 in the diagram. They are kind of fat and smallish. You’re looking at the broken bearings and cages from the free hub, not cartridge bearings from the hub body. Your cassette is wobbly because the freehub no longer has those bearings inside. :-)

Mystery unraveled!
As @Warren Burton suggested I've starting looking at the freeHub body bearings. Removed the outer one (6802-2RS) #5 on the photo. Then I realized this is the only cartridge bearing left. From the inner side of the freeHub body there is only a seal left (#2 on the photo). With careful inspection there is something like a thread - it turns out this is the outer metal ring (outer race) of the cartridge stuck in the freeHub body (#4 on the photo). So, where is the inner metal ring (inner race) of the cartridge?
And with more careful inspection it looks like it stucked on the axle :/ (#1 on the photo). Now the axle gets disassembled and the inner race is removed (saved the axle).


#1 inner race (stucked on the axle)
#2 cartridge seals (one left in the free hub body, other on the axle)
#3 ball bearings and the cage/retainer/crown (totally smashed)
#4 outer race (stucked in the freeHub body)
#5 outer cartridge bearings

Why I got confused?
First time finding the smashed ball bearings and the cage/retainer/crown, my thoughts were: What the hell are these things are doing there?, because I didn't see the race parts. If they dropped at the first time, I could save at least a week of wondering.
What is the situation now?
The outer race is well stuck in the free hub body, no way to push this out, already tried with a screwdriver and a hammer - no result.
How it happened?
I had several crashes with the bike, but not serous and not from jumping. Casual speed riding and losing control on the bike, however maybe one of them hit hard on the rear wheel and pushed the cassette and caused that situation.
What are the next steps?
I really wish only to replace the cartridge, but in this situation I have to buy a new free hub body. Of course it is not available in my country :/.
A closer look of the #4

Thanks again for your help and attention!

There might be other usable techniques for removing that outer race. Have you added penetrating oil yet? After doing that, you could try heating the freehub body/cooling the race, cutting a slot in the race to help break it, fracturing the race with a hard blow and sharp chisel-type tool, welding something to the race to help get a grip on it...

Not sure it deserves the effort, I found the complete FH-MT410-B hub at good price, from which I will take the free hub body and place it.

Should be relatively simple job for an engineering shop - I have no idea what would work best but have a few ideas that would probably work).  Question is not can they, it is how much it will cost vs new freehub.
